# How to initialize the first h in an RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Take a Vanilla RNN represented by the function $h_t = f(h_{t-1}, x_t)$, how do you determine $h_0$?

Edit: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251658/training-rnns-for-first-timestep) over on the stats page has helped.

Comment: Please write out what is relevant from the link. Links go stale, and not everybody is inclined to click around. Make it easy on the answerer!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways. One way is to always give it a zero vector, or some other constant that means "new sequence". Another way is to train the initial state vector just like you train any other weight: initialize it randomly, then apply gradient descent during training. The former is easier and faster, but the latter can sometimes make the RNN more effective.